# Vim Search and replace 2 or more integer values with 9 0s in a Visual Block using Visual Studio's Vim Plugin

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, vim, plugins, replace

Say I have

```
01
02
53
04
05
96
```

in a visual block.

I want to take all of them and convert them to '000000000'.

I am currently using the following expression but it does not seem to be working:

```
:\%V'<,'>s/[0-9]+/000000000/g
```

I keep getting a parse error. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this. Move the `\%V` into the substitute instead of before it. (I removed the `\` because I used very magic mode which was also necessary to use the unescaped `+`)

```
:'<,'>s/\v%V[0-9]+/000000000/g
```

Or you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`

Comment: That did not work, perhaps my problem is that I am using the visual studio vim pluggin and they don't support visual substitutions. Let me update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan What do you mean by it does not work? (I also don't have visual studio so I'm not sure how I can help there) Maybe also add sample input and output if the output is wrong.

Comment: I need to test this in cygwin's vim. If it works in there then I will give you the check until someone else or I can figure out why it works in a literal version of vim but not in Visual Studio's plugin. The only thing that I can provide is the output from the plugin. The output of your expression in VS2010 plugin output window is Pattern not found: \v%V\d+.

Comment: That did work in cygwin's vim. So my guess is going to be that there might be a special way to input that into the vim prompt inside the visual studio plugin.

Answer (score 2):

That `\%V` is a special *regular expression atom*; as such it belongs into the `{pattern}` part of the `:substitute` command, not in the `[range]` where you put it.

Since this is a specialty of Vim's regular expression dialect, it's likely that this isn't supported by the Vim emulation you're using. You can try to work around this with more common Vim features:

#### Alternative 1

1. In the blockwise selection, do `r0`. This should replace all existing digits with 0s.
2. Re-select with `gv`, then add the missing 0s via `I0000000<Esc>`

#### Alternative 2

You can copy / move the visual block into a separate area of empty lines somewhere, then apply a normal `3,6s//` command on that range, then delete the result (again blockwise) and paste it over / to the original selection.